# as_null_object not passing with two inputs

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm working through the RSpec Book, and I have the following test code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

module Codebreaker
  describe Game do
    describe "#start" do

      let(:output) { double('output').as_null_object }
      let(:game) { Game.new(output) }

      it "sends a welcome message" do
        output.should_receive(:puts).with('Welcome to Codebreaker!')
        game.start
      end

      it "prompts for the first guess" do
        output.should_receive(:puts).with('Enter guess:')
        game.start
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which corresponds to the following code:

```
module Codebreaker
  class Game
    def initialize(output)
      @output = output
    end

    def start
      @output.puts 'Welcome to Codebreaker!'
      @output.puts 'Enter a guess:'
    end
  end
end
```

Since I've set :output up as a double.as_null_object, I expect it to ignore any arguments/methods it is not expecting. For the first test (sends a welcome message), that's what it does, and it passes. The second test, however, is giving me this error:

```
Failure/Error: output.should_receive(:puts).with('Enter guess:')
   Double "output" received :puts with unexpected arguments
     expected: ("Enter guess:")
          got: ("Welcome to Codebreaker!"), ("Enter a guess:")
 # ./spec/codebreaker/game_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Codebreaker>'
```

Why is the double returning both "Welcome to Codebreaker!" and "Enter a guess" when I have explicitly told it to only expect "Enter a guess:", and how can I fix this while maintaining this same setup/structure?

Answer (score 0):

The second case is failing because you have a typo in your expectation. You meant `Enter a guess:` instead of `Enter guess:`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, rspec is very picky about wording on strings. In your start method you wrote `"Enter guess"` instead of `"Enter a guess:"`.

It's important to follow the wording to a T, when you start having to `raise` an error, rspec gives you a very nasty response.

Good luck! Rspec is a great tool as you get further into it.